# (gcloud.app.deploy): Error Response: The App Engine appspot and App Engine flexible environment service accounts must have permissions on the image

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to figure out the problem here.
I'm getting this error, trying to deploy an Angular app on a Google Cloud.
[image: Error Deploy]

I'm following the procedure here : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-angular-nginx-docker

I checked the post here but I doesn't help me : [ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy): The App Engine appspot and App Engine flexible environment service accounts must have permissions on the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72240436/error-gcloud-app-deploy-the-app-engine-appspot-and-app-engine-flexible-envir)

Here is my IAM :

[image]

And my app.yaml file :

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: default
threadsafe: true

env_variables:
  API_URL: "https://webapi-dev.appname.com"
```

I don't see why it's not regarding the error log and the role attributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your App Engine service account has the `Editor` role, however is the project ID correct? Based on the screenshot, the project ID is `yourprojectid` should it be a different value?

Comment: I think it's correct. I tried to add it manually by copying the Project Id on the landing page of my project and it said, the user and role existed already.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. I didn't change `yourprojectid` in `gcloud app deploy --image-url us.gcr.io/yourprojectid/angular-nginx-container`

Hope it will help somebody though.